# Unix Command Line Current Directory

Tags: bash, unix, directory

Let's say I have a folder structure like this:

```
mygame
 play.command
 otherstuff
  code.py
```

I want play.command to cd to mygame no matter where mygame is and run code.py from there. How do I do that?

Comment: What is `no matter where mygame is`? Still parent of `play.command`?

Comment: very very very very unclear question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put that `code.py` in `/bin` folder. Then you can access it from anywhere.

Comment: ... as long as you have that dir in your $PATH variable

Comment: It should be as comment

Comment: @MortezaLSC means what ? i should not have given answers here?

Comment: See this is a very short answer that could be as a comment...If the person who asks question understand your answer is best one you can put it here...but other answers you see have some detailes...'

Comment: @MortezaLSC..sorry i was not knowing this .since i was new

Answer (score 1):

From your question it seems you want to go to the parent directory. You do this via

```
cd ..
otherstuff/code.py
```

(with the space after 'cd')

or call `code.py` more directly with

```
../otherstuff/code.py
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying something like this,

You have two ways to run scripts:

1. absolute path:

   `python /path/to/script.py`
2. none-absolute path:

   `cd ../to/your/directory && python script.py`

Answer (score 0):

First cd to the directory where the script is stored in, and then execute the python script

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"
otherstuff/code.py
```